# How to write unit tests for suggested packages?

Tags: r, testthat

Packages in R can have different types of dependencies on other packages. Some of these types indicate hard requirements, i.e. `Depends`, `Imports` and `LinkingTo`.

However, there is a second category that indicate a softer dependency, i.e. `Suggests` and `Enhances`.  In both these cases, the package provides additional functionality if the suggested / enhanced package is available.

Here is a concrete example: The package [`checkpoint`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/checkpoint/index.html) imports `knitr` because `knitr` helps `checkpoint` to parse `rmarkdown` files.

But now I am considering changing `knitr` to a `Suggests` dependency, i.e. only provide this functionality if `knitr` is actually installed.

For proper unit testing, this means I have to test both scenarios:

1. If `knitr` is available, then do stuff.
2. If `knitr` is **not** available, then throw a warning and do nothing.

The actual R code is simple:

```
if(require(knitr)) {
  do_stuff()
} else {
  message("blah")
}
```

**Question**

But how can I set up unit tests for both scenarios?

The way I see it, the simple fact of checking for `require(knitr)` will load the `knitr` package if it is available in the local library.

So, to test for case 1, I have to install `knitr` locally, meaning I can't test for case 2.

**Is there a way of configuring `testthat` (or any other unit testing framework) for this use case?**

Comment: Would temporarily renaming the knitr folder be an acceptable solution?

Comment: @Dason Maybe, and this might work on my local machine.  But how do I manage this process on my continuous build integration machine (Jenkins or Travis) and how do I write this test to work on CRAN?

Comment: I would imagine that if you install knitr on those machines it goes into a folder where you have read/write privileges.  I suppose it would boil down to detecting if/where knitr is installed to by using `dir` on the entries in `.libPaths()` and then using `file.rename` to rename the knitr folder to something like knitr_BALEETED (or whatever you want) and then renaming it back to knitr after the tests are done.  I'm not sure how CRAN compliant this would be...

Comment: It's an interesting idea.  I'll try using `system.file()` to tell me the location.  To be honest, I'd be happy to disable the test on CRAN (easy to do with `testthat`) conditional on the test working locally and on Travis.

Comment: I didn't realize testthat had an option to skip_on_cran.  That... actually makes some of the stuff I've been working on easier.

Comment: Could use `find.package("knitr", quiet=TRUE)` to find an installed `knitr`, or `length(find.package("knitr", quiet=TRUE))` as a test for its presence on `.libPaths()`.

Comment: There's also the new `skip_if_not_installed()`, but that won't help here.  I'd make the function being tested switch behaviours based on an explicit argument, e.g. `knitr_installed = system.file(package="knitr") != ""`. Then you test could more easily evaluate both cases

Comment: This would only work with some setup ahead of time, and would fail on a standard installation (so should probably be used in conjunction with `skip_on_cran`), but you can put the suggested packages in a separate library and as part of the test setup make sure that library is/is not on the search path to test the two different cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### tl;dr

To test the branch followed when use `require(knitr)` fails, use `trace()` to temporarily modify `require()` so that it won't find **knitr**, even if it is present on `.libPaths()`. Specifically, in the body of `require()`, reset the value of `lib.loc=` to point to `R.home()` -- an existing directory that does not contain a `knitr` package.

This seems to work just as well in a package as it will in an interactive session in which you run the following:

```
find.package("knitr")

trace("require", quote(lib.loc <- R.home()), at=1)
isTRUE(suppressMessages(suppressWarnings(require(knitr))))

untrace("require")
isTRUE(suppressMessages(suppressWarnings(require(knitr))))
```

---

As I understand this, you have a function with two branches, one to be performed in R sessions for which `require(knitr)` succeeds, and the other to be performed in sessions where it fails. You are then wanting to test this function "both ways" from a single R instance in which **knitr** actually is on `.libPaths()`.

So basically you are needing some way to temporarily blind the call `require(knitr)` to the actual presence of **knitr**. Completely and temporarily resetting the value returned by `.libPaths()` looked promising, but doesn't seem to be possible.

Another promising avenue is to somehow reset the default value of `lib.loc` in calls to `require()` from `NULL` (which means "use the value of `.libPaths()`) to some other location where **knitr** is not available. You can't accomplish this by overwriting `base::require()`, nor (in a package) can you get there by defining a local masking version of `require()` with the desired value of `lib.loc`.

It does, though, look like you can get away with using `trace()` to temporarily modify `require()` (blinding it to **knitr**'s availability by setting `lib.loc=R.home()`). Then do `untrace()` to restore `require()` to the vanilla version which will  go ahead and find **knitr**.

Here's what that looked like in the dummy package I tested this with. First an R function that allows us to test for success along the two branches

```
## $PKG_SRC/R/hello.R

hello <- function(x=1) {
    if(require(knitr)) {
        x==2
    } else {
        x==3
    }
}
```

Then a couple of tests, one for each branch:

```
## $PKG_SRC/inst/tests/testme.R

## Test the second branch, run when require(knitr) fails
trace("require", quote(lib.loc <- R.home()), at=1)
stopifnot(hello(3))
untrace("require")

## Test the first branch, run when require(knitr) succeeds
stopifnot(hello(2))
```

To test this, I used `pkgKitten::kitten("dummy")` to set up a source directory, copied in these two files, added `Suggests: knitr` to the `DESCRIPTION` file, and then ran `devtools::install()` and `devtools::check()` from the appropriate directory. The package installs just fine, and passes all of the checks.

Comment: Even better might be to set `trace("require", quote(value <- FALSE), at=5)`. That will cause `require()` to return a value of `FALSE` even if **knitr** is already loaded, allowing you to pay less attention to the order in which you perform tests.

Comment: This is very nice. I have been working on something similar, using the `testthat::with_mock()` feature.  I suspect under the hood `with_mock` does something similar.

Comment: @Andrie Very cool, I hadn't seen that before. `trace()` will be nicer when you just want to change one or a few lines of a function, but `with_mock()` sure makes it easy to simply force a certain return value, which is all you need here.